# Erro na leitura de uma coluna de um arquivo .xlsx utilizando biblioteca pandas de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-excel, pandas

Preciso criar uma lista em Python a partir de uma coluna de um arquivo Excel utilizando a biblioteca pandas. Já fiz a instalação de todos os componentes da biblioteca e os arquivos estão no mesmo diretório.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

filename = r'email.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filename)

email = list[df['EMAIL']]

print(email)
```

Ao executar este arquivo, é acusado um erro na linha 7 do programa:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 7, in
>   
>       email = list[df['EMAIL']] TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Já procurei na documentação da biblioteca mas não consegui resolver.
Obrigado! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que assim deva funcionar

```
import pandas as pd

from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_excel('email.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha1')

email = df['EMAIL'].values.tolist()

print(email)
```

Comment: Funcionou!!!!!! Muito obrigado! <3

Comment: @GustavoSilva Favor ler [como aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/75104)